# Why is there no formula for some energies?

Tags: energy

There is no formula for solar energy, mechanical energy etc, 
 so Why there is no formulas for some energies?

Comment: The troubling subtext here is that you seem to be focused on formulas, and you might even be thinking there is a one-to-one correspondence between physics vocabulary words and physics formulas. This is really just not the case -- formulas are just another method of communicating ideas. Sometimes there are 15 formulas for a single concept, sometimes it's hard to point to any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are formulas and equations  involving energy in all branches of physics, it is almost impossible not to have some equation involving energy in any area of physics you study.

For example there is an equation for the luminosity of a star, which is the power emitted, which in turn is the energy per unit time put out by the star.

By using this equation we are able to estimate how much mass the star  contains, and what temperature the star is at its surface.

If you use Google to search for any specific  question, such as how much energy a car moving at 60 kilometres per hour  has, or how much energy it takes to heat a room, you will find an equation involving energy.

The unit of energy is the Joule, so if you see the word Joule, (or an equation with uppercase J in it), there is energy involved in the equation.

Look up "units of energy" on Wikipedia, and you will see lots of equations involving all types of energy, solar , mechanical etc.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, this question sounds ill-posed. What do you mean by "solar energy"? If you mean the energy given off in the form of light, than you can calculate this. The luminosity of the sun is the energy given off per unit time. The sun (to a good approximation) gives off it's energy in the form of blackbody radiation. You can integrate over the wavelengths of light to get the total energy given off in a unit area/unit time, than integrate over the surface of the sun to get the total energy given off per unit time.

If you mean energy recoverable by solar cells, that will be a engineering question based on how much energy hits your solar panel, and how much of that energy is actually able to be extracted (to charge a battery, for example).

For mechanical energy, what type of mechanical energy? Spring, gravitational potential (as in the energy stored when a roller coaster at the top of a hill), kinetic, pendulum, etc.